# How to make GUI and Graphics occur simultaneously?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am kind of new to Java programming.

I am facing difficulty in making both GUI, and Graphics exist at the same time. 
For example, if I want to display a `JButton` and a ball on the `JFrame`, the code doesn't work for me.

Here is the code I used:

```
package paint;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PAINT extends JFrame{
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;
JButton b;

public PAINT(){ //Class constructor for the JFrame
    super("THE TITLE");
    setSize(500,500);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    b = new JButton("Enter");
    add(b);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){ //Double Buffering
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(300, 300, 40,40); //To paint the ball
    repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new PAINT();
}
}
```

With this code, only a large ball is displayed without the button.

Comment: Okay, some red flags here. First of all, JFrames are already double-buffered so you are doing work that's already being done in your `paint`. Which is the second red flag: Never overwrite the `paint` method. Only ever override the `paintComponent`. Then always call `super.paintComponent(g)` in your overriden `paintComponent` if you aren't filling the full screen space (as you aren't currently) to avoid bad repaints occuring. And finally (more code style, not red flag): Add `@Override` to your overriden methods to make it clear that it's an overriden method (and avoid faulty signatures)

Answer (score 0):

First, go read [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how painting works in Swing.

Next, avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, these are complex and composite components and because of the way painting works, tend to cause more issue then they solve.

When done properly, painting is series of chained method calls, allowing you to better customise the process. As a general recommendation, the best place to start is with `paintComponent`.  Because of the nature of the painting process, you should also call the methods `super` implementation, unless you are fully aware of the what it's doing and are prepared to take over it's responsibility.

Swing components, are themselves, double buffered by default, which is another reason to override using `paint` from `JFrame`

A solution might look something like...

[image: And now it works]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Paint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Paint();
    }

    public Paint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        JButton b;

        public TestPane() {
            b = new JButton("Enter");
            add(b);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillOval(300, 300, 40, 40); //To paint the ball
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```